r-vector's recursive definition
I am a student studying physics and I am reading Space-Time Algebra by David Hestenes. In the chapter 1 section 3 ,he talks about recursive definition of  a simple r-vector:
$${A_{{\rm{r}} + 1}} = a \wedge {A_r} = \frac{1}{2}(a{A_r} + {( - 1)^r}{A_r}a) = a \wedge {a_1} \wedge ... \wedge {a_r}$$
I think it's confusing. I don't know where the $(-1)^r$ comes from. I tried to understand it but still can't get an satisfactory answer.
I've tried to use $a \wedge b = \frac{1}{2}(ab - ba)$ but if $A_r$ behaves just like a normal vector, contrasting these two, it shouldn't be $(-1)^r$ in the middle. Instead  it should be $(-1)$.
So I choose another way to do it and use $ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b$ . After taking it into the equation of ${A_{{\rm{r}} + 1}}$,I got an equation
$${A_{{\rm{r}} + 1}}=\frac{1}{2}(a \cdot {A_r} + a \wedge {A_r} + {( - 1)^r}{A_r} \cdot a + {( - 1)^r}{A_r} \wedge a)$$
But there is a confusing part-the inner product term .When the $r$ is even ,then inner product term cann't be canceled. How do I solve this problem?

It is true that $a\wedge b = -b\wedge a$ for vectors $a,b$. Now, using this fact, what happens when you try to "commute" $a$ with $b_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge b_r$? In other words, what is the relationship between $$a\wedge b_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge b_r$$ and $$b_1\wedge\dotsb\wedge b_r\wedge a$$

You also seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding. The identity $ab = a\cdot b + a\wedge b$ is only true for vectors $a,b$. It is not true for arbitrary multivectors.

But it is true for all vectors a and all multivectors b.
